# Creating a sequence of all values in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm currently working on a kata code challenge and it comes with a few requirements:

1. The number u(0) = 1 is the first one in u.
2. For each x in u, then y = 2 * x + 1 and z = 3 * x + 1 must be in u too.
3. There are no other numbers in u.

I have constructed a few functions:

```
(defn test2 [x n orgN] ;;x is a counter, n is what I want returned as a list
  (println n)
  (println "this is x: " x)
  (cons n (if (not= x (- orgN 1 )) 
   (do (test2 (+ x 1) (+ 1 (* n 2)) orgN)
   (test2  (+ x 1) (+ 1 (* n 3)) orgN))
  nil)
))

(defn test2helper [n]
  (def x 1)
  (test2 x x n) 
)


(test2helper 5)
```

However this only returns (1 4 13 40) and misses a whole bunch of values in between. Cons is only constructing a list based on the last 3n+1 algorithm and not picking up any other values when I want instead a sequence of the two values generated from each n value repeated. My question is is there a way to construct a sequence of all the values instead of just 4 of them?

https://www.codewars.com/kata/twice-linear/train/clojure

Comment: we don't solve homework assignments and exercises here, Sean. refer to a Clojure programming tutorial.

Comment: Alternatively, break down the problem to the part in the code's behaviour that you don't understand and present a specific question. In the process you might find the right way to construct the function.

Comment: @Carcigenicate It's hard to see how `iterate` would be useful here. This algorithm is fundamentally recursive, and can't obviously be made iterative.

Comment: @amalloy Yes, I tried writing it out and realized that I misinterpreted the problem. I meant to delete that comment.

Comment: Perhaps instead of editing the question, you should create a new question with your later problem

Comment: I've rolled back the edit. Please create a new question when you have something new to ask.

Answer (score 1):

This solution is pretty close to being correct. But remember that `do` is for performing side effects, not for producing values. Specifically, `(do x y)` returns `y` after performing the side effects in `x`. But `test2` does not have any side effects: it just returns a list. What you are looking for is instead `(concat x y)`, a function which concatenates two lists together into a larger list.

Comment: how do I explicitly tell the program to just construct a sequence of value n from there? I'm very new to this language and I'm still trying to wrap my head around it but I appreciate your help

Comment: As I said, just replace `do` with `concat`. That's all that needs to be changed.

Comment: Hmm, all that did was return an empty list

Comment: Nevermind, I got it working now!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Although [Alan Malloy's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53510852/1562315) answers your question, it does not solve [the problem you refer to](https://www.codewars.com/kata/twice-linear/train/clojure), which requires that the sequence is generated in increasing order.

My approach would be to generate the sequence lazily, according to the following pattern:

```
(defn recurrence [f inits]
  (map first (iterate f inits)))
```

For example, you can define the Fibonacci sequence like this:

```
(defn fibonacci []
  (recurrence (fn [[a b]] [b (+ a b)]) [1 1]))

=> (take 10 (fibonacci))
(1 1 2 3 5 8 13 21 34 55)
```

The sequence you need is harder to generate. Good hunting!

---